# ReactJS: How to create a slider that act as an ON/OFF button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am curious to know how I could create a button appearing like a slider. I guess the best example would be something like this [slider](https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1461161528slide_to_unlock.jpg).

And what would be even greater is to have it around a rounded object kind of in the shape of [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6XWN.png).

To be more precise I need a slider doing half a circle and acting like an ON/OFF button not setting a value but just turning ON at 100%.

I have looked everywhere that I could think of and do not seem to find a way to do it. May be I am just not thinking properly to execute it but nonetheless I don't seem to find a way.

Hope I made myself clear, thank you.

ps : see more details in second comment just below.

Comment: You could probably wrap MaterialUI circular progress in a button and attach an onClick listener to it which changes its state on every click.

https://material-ui.com/components/progress/#CircularWithValueLabel.js

Or you could make a circular div, with a text inside (ON/OFF), which toggles on button click

Comment: Okay first of all, thanks guys for your answers but the thing is I am looking for a slider (from 0 to 100%) with the capacity to trigger an ON/OFF switch ; for ex. the volume on youtube but instead of setting the volume I just want it to trigger a state for exemple at 100% (or even 95% for effectiveness) and kind of do nothing below it. Almost like the old slider to unlock screen on smartphone, if you don't go full on the slider the screen stays locked. I know it is weird but it is just for an artist website and if possible make this kind of slider but half circle instead of straight line.

Comment: @Othman I think the below examples of roundSlider is suitable for your requirement, check the below link. If you have the mock screenshot of your exact requirement then I can suggest a better example. 

https://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#various-circle-shapes

Comment: wow this sound great I wanted to make it from scratch but if jQuery allows me that I will go on this road thank a lot dude. I am looking at it right now it is enough for me to consider my question answered thank you again, and to everyone else who took the time to read and/or answer.

Comment: If you want this for reactjs, then you can use jQuery plugins in react as well. here a simple wrapper for roundSlider to use with react.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jquery-round-slider

Answer (score 1):

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
}

label .fill {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: 0.4s left;
}

label input {
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
label input:checked + span.fill {
  left: calc(100% - 22px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="fill"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Hope this simple example can help you for creating a simple switcher.